# Linked List-Singly linked list .......why do we use location == 1?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

#While I was studying linked list, i came across a doubt. I could not understand while adding a node or removing a node from the end the location was 1.Can anyone help me out?
#Why location == 1 for adding/ removing from end side?
#Please explain !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next
    # insert in Linked List
    def insertSLL(self, value, location):
        newNode = Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            if location == 0:
                newNode.next = self.head
                self.head = newNode
            elif location == 1:
                newNode.next = None
                self.tail.next = newNode
                self.tail = newNode
            else:
                tempNode = self.head
                index = 0
                while index < location - 1:
                    tempNode = tempNode.next
                    index += 1
                nextNode = tempNode.next
                tempNode.next = newNode
                newNode.next = nextNode
    def deleteNode(self, location):
        if self.head is None:
            print("The SLL does not exist")
        else:
            if location == 0:
                if self.head == self.tail:
                    self.head = None
                    self.tail = None
                else:
                    self.head = self.head.next
            elif location == 1:
                if self.head == self.tail:
                    self.head = None
                    self.tail = None
                else:
                    node = self.head
                    while node is not None:
                        if node.next == self.tail:
                            break
                        node = node.next
                    node.next = None
                    self.tail = node
            else:
                tempNode = self.head
                index = 0
                while index < location - 1:
                    tempNode = tempNode.next
                    index += 1
                nextNode = tempNode.next
                tempNode.next = nextNode.next
```

Comment: It appears that 1 and 0 are "magic numbers" representing the head node and the tail node respectively.  All other values of `location` are treated as the "number" of the node to delete (e.g., a location of 3 means deleted the third node).

Answer (score 0):

Inserting at the beginning and end have to be treated specially.

To insert at the beginning you assign the `head` attribute of the list rather than the `next` attribute of the previous node (because there is no previous node).

When you insert at the end, you have to update the `tail` attribute of the list in addition to linking it to the old tail via its `next` attribute.